# Ajax POST to controller action to update view model, and then reload div

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net

I'm still shaky with my use of ajax so there are a couple holes in my implementation here. I am trying to post to a controller action that will call a stored procedure to update my view model and then reload the div that will display the information.

Ajax Post:

```
$("#order-summary-panel").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetOrderSummary", "Home")',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function() {
          alert("It Worked!")
        }
    });
});
```

Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetOrderSummary
{
    using (var entity = new OrderEntities())
    {
         var user = User.Identity.Name;
         var orderSummary = entity.uspGetOrderSummary(user).ToList();
         var viewModel = new OrderViewModel
         {
             OrderSummary = orderSummary
         };

         return View("Index", viewModel)
    }
}
```

Div to reload:

```
<div id="order-summary-panel">
    @if (Model != null && Model.OrderSummary != null)
    {
        foreach (var order in Model.OrderSummary)
        {
         // Display Orders
        }
    }
</div>
```

I believe that I shouldn't be returning the full view, but I am not sure how to update the view model without doing so. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could return a PartialView and put the result in a div, for sample:

### PartialView

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetOrderSummary
{
    using (var entity = new OrderEntities())
    {
         var user = User.Identity.Name;
         var orderSummary = entity.uspGetOrderSummary(user).ToList();
         var viewModel = new OrderViewModel
         {
             OrderSummary = orderSummary
         };

         return PartialView("Index", viewModel);
    }
}
```

and in your javascript:

```
$("#order-summary-panel").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetOrderSummary", "Home")',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data) {  // check if data is defined
               $("#order-summary-panel").html(data);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

### Json

You also could try to return a `json` an manipulate the html (which can improve the performance), for sample:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetOrderSummary
{
    using (var entity = new OrderEntities())
    {
         var user = User.Identity.Name;
         var orderSummary = entity.uspGetOrderSummary(user).ToList();
         var viewModel = new OrderViewModel
         {
             OrderSummary = orderSummary
         };

         return Json(new { success = true, order = viewModel }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }
}
```

And in your Javascript, you could try to read these properties:

```
$("#order-summary-panel").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetOrderSummary", "Home")',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data) {  // check if data is defined
               if (data.success) { // if success is true
                   alert("It Worked!"); 
                   // you could read data.order
               }
            }
        }
    });
});
```