# Display Information from LINQ query

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

So I have a string that has been passed from JS to my controller like so:

**JavaScript**

```
function findEmployees(userCounty) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '@Url.Action("getCounty", "Contact")',
        data: JSON.stringify(userCounty),
        contentType: "application/json",
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index([FromBody] string userCounty)
    {
        var county = userCounty.Substring(0, userCounty.IndexOf(" "));
        var query = from m in _context.model where m.county == county select new Model 
        {
          FirstName = m.Firstname
          LastName = m.LastName
        };

        if (query == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(query.ToList());
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**View**

```
@model Project.Models.ModelName
<table class="table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am able to pass the string from JS to my controller and query the database but how do I update the page to show the results of the query in my view? Anything helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data returned by ajax is text or json. If you want to use c# to update the page. You can make action `getCounty` return partial view, partial view automatically returns data with html.

Change action `getCounty`.

```
    [HttpPost("getCounty")]
    public ActionResult Index([FromBody] string userCounty)
    {
        var county = userCounty.Substring(0, userCounty.IndexOf(" "));
        //...
        return PartialView(query.ToList());
    }
```

PartialView **Index.cshtml**

```
@model List<ModelName>
<table class="table">
<tbody>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].LastName)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

**View**

```
@model ModelName
<div id="datalist">
    
</div>
<!--other code-->
@section Scripts{
    <script>
    function findEmployees(userCounty) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //dataType: "json",
            url: '@Url.Action("getCounty", "Contact")',
            data: JSON.stringify(userCounty),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#datalist').html(data)
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
}
```

It can generate different data tables according to userCounty

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: So do I need to make a new file for my partial view? I'm sorry I am very unfamiliar with partial views. Edit: Im also getting an error telling me that "(model => model[i].FirstName)" is not set to an instance of an object. Is that a problem with the controller?

Comment: To others that read this: After being involved in this project through another question, I suspect the case is classic X/Y. OP started using Ajax for posting data, while he should have been using plain form. Hence, solving an issue, leads to other issues until app is ready the StackOverflow way.

Comment: Yes, you need to generate a new file according to partial view. For this error, please check whether the reference of `@model List<ModelName>` is correct. And this is the partial view's [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list to the page like this.You can then press inside a div or ul list with each loop.

```
function findEmployees(userCounty) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: '@Url.Action("getCounty", "Contact")',
            data: JSON.stringify(userCounty),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.data.length !== 0) {
                    $.each(result.data, function (index, value) {
                        var firstName = value.firstName;
                        var lastName = value.lastName;
                    });
                }
            },
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do it using C# instead?

Comment: Okey, your answer is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975369/ajax-post-to-controller-action-to-update-view-model-and-then-reload-div